# Why can't a user create tables in a database (they own) with a script? SP permission issue perhaps?

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, permissions, dbo

I granted a user permission to create databases.  They were able to create a database, which they now own, but they are getting errors when running a script to create the tables.  I don't have a lot of information at this point (sorry!), so I can't diagnose it myself, but perhaps someone more experienced in database permissions could help.

I'm assuming they are using some built-in stored procedures and it's a some kind of permission issue.  I assumed that if they can create/own a database, they can do whatever they want to it, but there must be something they don't have access to.

Any advise?  Do I need to grant them permissions beyond "create database"?  Is there some common/standard set of stored procedures they should have access to?  Do they need access to "master" database?

Comment: I would first check for any DATABASE-level triggers that are attached to the MODEL database

Comment: There are no triggers on the "model" database, because in SSMS the node at [SQLServer]->[Databases]->[System Databases]->[model]->[Programmability]->[Database Triggers] is empty.

Answer (score 1):

"Owning" the database at the *server level* is different to being "db_owner" *in* the database

After creating the database, run this

```
CREATE USER foo FOR LOGIN foo
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'foo'
```

See [CREATE USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) for more info

Edit: Relying on any owner to dbo mapping from CREATE DATABASE is unreliable: set permissions explicitly or use sp_changedbowner

Comment: The login 'foo' created the database, so they already have the 'db_owner' role in the database.  Specifically, the user 'dbo' in the database has the 'db_owner' role and user 'dbo' is associated with login 'foo'.  Like I said, since 'foo' created the database, shouldn't 'foo' be able to create tables in it, since they own it completely (at both the server-level and have the db_owner role in it)?

Comment: I'm really trying to figure out or get ideas about what else could be preventing a script from creating tables in a database the user created and owns.

Comment: @Triynko: CREATE DATABASE *does not set* the user or roles in the database: which is why I gave this answer. Relying on the dbo mapping is unreliable: set permissions explicitly

Comment: This is not making any sense.  'dbo' user is mapped to 'foo' login.  Login 'foo' cannot create a user named 'foo' in the database, because login 'foo' is already associated with user 'dbo'.  The error is "The login already has an account under a different user name. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15063)".  The mapping IS reliable.  If user 'dbo' has 'db_owner' role and is mapped to login 'foo', then login 'foo' is owner and functions as user 'dbo' with all permissions of 'dbo', which as 'db_owner' is ALL PERMISSIONS.

Comment: If a user has the 'db_owner' role, and the user is mapped to the current login, then doesn't the current login, being mapped to a user that is 'db_owner' have permission to do anything at all in the database?  Seems pretty straightforward and reliable to me.

Comment: I may end up deleting this post, because I got some more info and it seems the problem is entirely unrelated to permissions.  The script is just trying to do something stupid like create a user for a login that doesn't exist.  Geez.   But I'd still like to clarify this whole thing about being 'db_owner' isn't enough....